# Bordless button with custom background button

Tags: android, material-design

Min sdk: 19.
I want to have next button (button without any margings from screen edge) with accent background color `accent=#ff9800`:

[image]

What's I try?

```
<Button
            style="@style/Button.Default"
            android:id="@+id/next"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/continue_text"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>

<style name="Button.Default" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless.Colored">
        <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/accent</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

But get:

[image]

Also still available marings on highilight click:

[image]

How I can solve my issue?

Comment: What's your min sdk? You can use backgroundTint for 21 and up

Comment: @A.K.S.H., api 19. I try on google emulator with api-21. As: `style="@style/Button.Default" android:backgroundTint="@color/accent"` -same result, but now I have no ripple effect on click. With only one `android:backgroundTint="@color/accent"` - default button with margins.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, you should define default button theme in your AppTheme like this

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/Button.Default</item>
</style>
```

And then instead of `style="@style/Button.Default"`use `android:theme="@style/Button.Default"`

Comment: Apply to application theme AppTheme and change at button as your wrote: http://i.imgur.com/RTKKuGT.png + highlight do not works.

Answer (score 0):

In your button :

```
<Button
        style="@style/Button.Default"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/next"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/continue_text"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>
```

In your style:

```
<style name="Button.Default" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless.Colored">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/background_button</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

Make a new drawable `background_button.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:color="@color/colorPrimary"
    tools:targetApi="lollipop">
    <item android:id="@android:id/mask">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:id="@android:id/background"
        android:drawable="@color/colorAccent" />
</ripple>
```

Use whatever color you want as ripple color in place of `@color/colorPrimary`

Comment: Margings to 0dp not needed, but button lost ripple-effect, because android:background override all.